# Using AWS RDS Postgresql database with a login from secrets manager

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

So, I've been looking around for more details, but can't find it.

I have a AWS RDS Postgresql cluster. In the typical sense, when I want to add a login to my database, I use the

create user  xxxx with password 'yyy'

then I grant that user access to the tables and other rights.

Now, I tried to add another user with secrets manager linked to this RDS database.

I'm not sure what to do next....should that new user I only created in secrets, appear in the login for the database, because I don't see it?  How would we grant access to the tables and other things for that user?